# adding same element to multiple forms javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Code:

```
<script  language=javascript type="text/javascript">

  var city = new Array("Pune","Mumbai"); 

  var selObj = document.forms["apmc_create"].elements["apmc_city_name"];

  for (var i=0; i < city.length;++i)
  {

  addOption(selObj, city[i], city[i]);
  }

  function addOption(selectbox,text,value)
  {
  //document.write("ramesh");
  var optn = document.createElement("option");
  optn.text = text;
  optn.value = value;
  selectbox.options.add(optn);
  }

  </script>
```

In above code, I have added select dropdown to form name `apmc_create`. Now I want to add same select dropdown to another form name `apmc_edit`.

How should I add same element to multiple forms in above code?

coding like `var selObj = document.forms["apmc_create","apmc_edit"].elements["apmc_city_name"];` is not working on both pages.

Please guide.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clone()` method with `TRUE` value for copy keeping functionality.

**exemple:**

```
$("p").clone(true).appendTo("body");
```

source : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_clone.asp